# "sp_spaceused" returns only one result set in perl

Tags: sql-server, perl

When I used the "sp_spaceused" in SQL server editor it returns two result set.

i.e.

```
database_name, database_size, unallocated space

'Test', '25000.00 MB', '4510.67 MB'
```

and

```
reserved, data, index_size, unused

'10741072 KB', '10007904 KB', '661728 KB', '71440 KB'
```

But in perl script it returns only one.

EX:

```
my $query = "sp_spaceused";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query) ;
$sth->execute();

while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() )

{

    print " @row \n ";

}
```

Output:

```
database_name, database_size, unallocated space

'Test', '25000.00 MB', '4510.67 MB'
```

Is there any way to fetch and store both the result set !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (taken from [here](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/perl/sql_server_unix_tutorial.html))

```
do {
    while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() )
    {
        print " @row \n ";
    }
} while ($sth->{odbc_more_results});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your suggestion worked fine for the stored procedure results.